# How to get mac address given a host ip in windows

Tags: windows, networking

When I run ipconfig I get an ethernet (10.27.1.13) and wireless (10.27.1.16) host ip addresses.

When I run arp -a 10.27.1.13 or arp -a 10.27.1.16 I get 'No Arp entries found'.

When I run arp -a I get

```
Interface: 10.27.1.16 --- 0xb
Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  10.27.0.1             00-23-5e-56-82-7f     dynamic
  10.27.0.10            78-2b-cb-98-83-ce     dynamic


Interface: 10.27.1.13 --- 0xe
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  10.27.0.1             00-23-5e-56-82-7f     dynamic
  10.27.0.10            78-2b-cb-98-83-ce     dynamic
```

I'm trying to run arp -a 10.27.1.16 and get a mac address for this interface but it says 'no arp entries found'. Do you know why this is happening and what the solution is?

Answer (score 0):

```
arp -a -N 10.27.1.13
arp -a -N 10.27.1.16
```

Read (exempt from) `arp /?`:

```
ARP -a [inet_addr] [-N if_addr] [-v]

  -a            Displays current ARP entries by interrogating the current
                protocol data.  If inet_addr is specified, the IP and Physical
                addresses for only the specified computer are displayed.  If
                more than one network interface uses ARP, entries for each ARP
                table are displayed.
  -g            Same as -a.
  inet_addr     Specifies an internet address.
  -N if_addr    Displays the ARP entries for the network interface specified
                by if_addr.
```